# How to sort queryset by

Tags: python, django

There are two related classes in my code:

```
class TreeNode(MPTTModel):
    ...
    @property
    def last_payment(self):
         return self.annuities.last()

class FilterPayment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'взнос за фильтр'
        verbose_name_plural = 'взносы за фильтр'

    expected_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='ожидаемая дата')
    fact_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='фактическая дата', null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='сумма')
    client = models.ForeignKey(TreeNode, related_name='annuities', verbose_name='клиент')
```

How to filter `TreeNode.objects.all()` by `last_payment__expected_date` if `last_payment` is property?

Comment: No you can't do that on queryset. You could sort using python sorted function with the `key` parameter related to `last_payment()` method: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions. Or you have a field that always record the `last_payment`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a property to filter on Django Querysets. You can, though, do the following which will give you the desired result:

```
import datetime
TreeNode.objects.filter(annuities__expected_date = datetime.datetime(YYYY, MM, DD))
```